# Error in Spivak's "Calculus on Manifolds". Construction of function composition for proof of change of variables

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions, differential-geometry, change-of-variable

"Calculus on Manifolds", Proof of Change of Variables theorem.
I don't understand how letting $U=k^{-1}(V)$ leads to $h(U)\subset V$. It would most definitely make sense if we let $U=h^{-1}(V)$[image][image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, it is a typo. $k$ is defined on $h(U')$ and we have $h(a) \in V \subset h(U')$, thus we must of course take $U =h^{-1}(V) \subset U'$ in order to get $h(U) \subset V$.

Comment: Thanks, It's always nice to be able to verify my doubts regarding typos in books, just to make sure  Useful for me and everybody else who's reading the book and knows how to use Google as well